# Finding exact amount of used RAM in OpenStack's web interface Horizon

Tags: openstack

In OpenStack's web interface Horizon I can see:

[image]

Is there any way to have a more precise figure on how much RAM is being used?

The best I have found so far is to look at the page source:

[image]

but it only gives me a number rounded at the nearest percentage (here 98%). I would like to know precisely how many GB of RAM are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the exact amount of used RAM in the pop-up that appears when you click on  <kbd>Launch Instance</kbd> :

[image]

[image]

Alternately you can go to `Project Overview`, then `Download CSV Summary`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what 'Active Ram' means here? Is that an average over the whole period, or the lowest or highest, or something else?