# Which instances' states count toward the project's RAM quota on OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

Looking at the [CSV Summary](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/track_usage.html) through OpenStack's web interface Horizon (under Project Overview), I see that the instances of my project are in various states, namely:

- [1](https://serverfault.com/q/616368/126950)
- Active
- Error
- Stopped/Shutoff
- Suspended

Which instances' states count toward the project's RAM quota on OpenStack? I.e. if the instance is in state X, will it be counted in the RAM quota of the project?

(I did try to do the math using the CSV Summary, but the figures seems to be slightly buggy, and don't correspond to the [actual amount of used RAM](https://serverfault.com/q/613749/126950))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count toward RAM quota:

- Active
- [Paused](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/pause_server.html):

  > The pause command stores the state of the VM in RAM. A paused instance
  >   continues to run in a frozen state.
- [Suspend](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/suspend_resume.html): the documentation says the following

  > Administrative users might want to suspend an instance if it is
  >   infrequently used or to perform system maintenance. When you suspend
  >   an instance, its VM state is stored on disk, all memory is written to
  >   disk, and the virtual machine is stopped. Suspending an instance is
  >   similar to placing a device in hibernation; memory and vCPUs become
  >   available to create other instances.

  But it is [still counted in RAM quota](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openstack/dev/39229), even though the RAM is released so that it can be used by other projects, for example. Confirmed by own testing.
- Stopped (own testing)

---

Doesn't count toward RAM quora:

- [1](https://serverfault.com/q/616368/126950) (own testing)

---

Regarding the error state, whether it counts toward RAM quora depends on when the error occurred: if it is a scheduling error (i.e. error when trying to allocate resources to a newly started node), then error doesn't count toward RAM quota. Otherwise, it does.